# Why is my Stripe Charge suddenly not working?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Has Stripe changed something? I have used this code snippet before and now suddenly there is error (Exception $e)? This error is appearing suddenly have fought with in for an hour now

```
try {

    //Charge the Card
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "customer" => $stripe_account,
    "amount" => 450,
    "currency" => "eur",
    'capture' => true),
    );
    
    $chargeID = $charge->id;
    
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
    
        //Send User to Error Page
        echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>205)); 
    exit();
    
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
    
        //Send User to Error Page
         echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>205));    
         exit();
    
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
        echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>205)); 
        //Send User to Error Page
    
    exit();
    
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //Send User to Error Page
        echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>205)); 
        //Send User to Error Page
    
    exit();
    
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: @RobRuchte okay fixed it myself. The error said that there was no API key then but there was and i double checked it. After i issued new API key it worked. Thanks anyway!

Comment: `Has Stripe changed something?` ... though you found the issue, would that not be a question for Stripe since stackoverflow does not manage Stripe?

Comment: @PaulT. of course but i didn't knew before Rob gave me the brilliant idea to check the exception message and stack trace so the question was like thought for everybody who had knowledge about changes which could affect my code. But sure it's a question for Stripe why it helped changing the API Token

Answer (score 0):

This issues was fixed by changing the API key. Which makes no sense i've been in contact with Stripe which is now researching this. But it works now.

Comment: My experience with Stripe support is they're super-responsive to questions about this sort of thing.  Once you convince them of your identity they move heaven and earth to fix this kind of problem. Of course. You can't get paid? They don't get paid either.